# C++ : Unable to read from large txt file

Tags: c++, input, vector, mergesort

I'am new to c++..I wrote a code for mergesort algorithm. My problem is I want to read 100,000 integers from a txt file as input,
I tried my code with smaller inputs and it worked. But when I'am using large file it's getting stopped.
I used vectors to allocate memory dynamically.
I used long datatype is there any mistake with that?
My code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
#include<conio.h>

void merge(vector<long> &,long ,long , long );


void divide(vector<long> &arr,long min, long max){
    long mid;

    if(min<max){
        mid=(min+max)/2;
        divide(arr,min,mid);
        divide(arr,mid+1,max);
        merge(arr,min,mid,max);
    }
    return;

}

void merge(vector<long> &arr,long min, long mid,long max){
    long i,j,k;
    long c[30];

    i=min,j=mid+1;
    k=min;

    while(i<=mid && j<=max){
        if(arr[i]<arr[j]){
            c[k]=arr[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        else{
            c[k]=arr[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }
    while(i<=mid){
        c[k]=arr[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while(j<=max){
        c[k]=arr[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }

    for(long i=min;i<k;i++)
        arr[i]=c[i];
}

int main(){

    vector<long> data;
    long tmp;
    long count=0;

    ifstream fin("sample2.txt");

    while(fin >> tmp)
    {
        data.push_back(tmp);
        count++;
    }

    divide(data,0,count);

    cout<<"the sorted array is";
    for(long i=0;i<count;i++)
        cout<<data[i]<<"\n";

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What specific errors are you getting? When or how does the program stop? Please clarify the issues you are experiencing!

Comment: The .exe file stops responding..I get a warning message mergesort.exe stopped working..

Comment: Thats not an error, thats a symptom.

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger, see what it's doing right, where it's going wrong.

Comment: Also, as @GingerPlusPlus mentionned, you should learn to indent your code appropriately, as well as standard code formatting, because the code you provided us was painful to read!

Comment: ohh... really sorry for that.. this is my first question.. I didn't knew that..sorry.

Comment: It's not just for the sake of the question; it's important to learn how to format your code in an appropriate manner. If you do, you'll navigate more easily in your code, and other people with understand it more easily too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the merge function:

you exceed the local variable c.

`long c[30];`

maybe there are more problems, that is the first I notice.

## EDIT

Try this: find the differences...

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

void merge(vector<long> &,long ,long , long );


void divide(vector<long> &arr,long min, long max){
    long mid;

    if(min<max){
        mid=(min+max)/2;
        if(min != mid) divide(arr,min,mid);
        if(max != mid+1) divide(arr,mid+1,max);
        merge(arr,min,mid,max);
    }
    return;

}

void merge(vector<long> &arr,long min, long mid,long max){
    long i,j,k;
    map<long,long> c; //uses map because the vector not always start from 0
    //other option is to use vector<long> c(max-min) and substruct min when copy to/from it.
    //like this: vector<long> c(1+max-min); //initialize size = max-min+1
    //           c[k-min] = arr[i];
    //           arr[i] = c[i-min];
    i=min,j=mid+1;
    k=min;

    while(i<=mid && j<=max){
        if(arr[i]<arr[j]){
            c[k]=arr[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        else{
            c[k]=arr[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }
    while(i<=mid){
        c[k]=arr[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while(j<=max){
        c[k]=arr[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }

    for(long i=min;i<=max;i++)
        arr[i]=c[i];
}

void create_input(int i){
    srand(time(NULL));
    ofstream fout("sample2.txt");
    while(i--){
        fout<<rand()<<" ";
    }
} 

int main(){

    vector<long> data;
    long tmp;
    long count=0;
    //create random input
    //create_input(31);

    ifstream fin("sample2.txt");

    while(fin >> tmp)
    {
        data.push_back(tmp);
        count++;//count = data.size(); !!
    }
    cout<<"the unsorted array is\n";
    for(long i=0;i<count;i++)
        cout<<i<<"]\t"<<data[i]<<"\n";

    divide(data,0,count-1);//use last index not size

    cout<<"the sorted array is\n";
    for(long i=0;i<count;i++)
        cout<<i<<"]\t"<<data[i]<<"\n";


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it didn't solve my problem, i'am still stuck there.

Comment: Why dont you use a vector instead of the const array size? currently it limits your file to 30 numbers... try file with 30 numbers, than try with 31...

Comment: i used vector<long> c; is this the right way?

Comment: it's working if i give c[1000000] but I think it's not a good way..can you plz give me syntax in vectors?

Answer (score -2):

Your program is causing a stack overflow

Comment: That's not an answer, that's a comment...

Comment: That is an answer, because that is what's happening. The long answer is to rewrite the code so that it does smaller chunks at a time

Comment: The keys of a good answer is to be precise and helpful. Yours barely respect the second point. `Your program is causing a stack overflow` Where? Why? What can you suggest to solve or work around the problem?